# Plotting confidence and means from logistic regression in ggplot2

Tags: regression, logistic, confidence-interval, lme4-nlme, ggplot2

My data are for an experiment asking participants to detect a tone (Response= 1 or 0) in different (within-participant) conditions. I am interested in how participants' scores on separate questionnaires affect task performance.

I run a series of logistic mixed models with different covariates and predictors of experimental interest, but this is one model as an example:

```r
model <- glmer(Response ~ sumcaps + sumpdi + sumspq + (1|Pt_ID), 
               family= binomial, data = lme.df, 
               control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"))
```

This model is run twice: once with only Condition 'No tone' trials, and once with only Condition '25%' trials.

I want to create separate plots for each questionnaire score (sumpdi, sumcaps, sumspq) showing the relationship between score and the likelihood of responding '1' in the task (with both conditions on the same plot, separate lines).

For example, with `sumpdi`:

```r
agg_forplot <- aggregate(Response ~ sumpdi+ Condition+Pt_ID, 
                         df_forplot, FUN=mean)

Plot_C1 <- ggplot(agg_forplot, aes(x=sumpdi, y=Response, 
                                   colour=Condition)) + 
     geom_smooth(method='lm', se=T, fill='light blue') + 
     geom_point() +
     ylab("Mean % 'Tone Present' Responses") +
     xlab('Summary PDI Score') + labs(color= 'Condition') +
     scale_color_manual(labels = c("No tone", "25%"), 
                                    values= c("#5CC0C0","#FF88FF"))
```

[image: Plot C1 Output]

I understand that each of the points on this graph represents the mean likelihood of Response=1 for each participant. The line plot is then the mean across participants, and the shaded area is the 95% confidence interval created by geom_smooth().

As each participant only has one sumpdi score, I thought initially thought that participant ('Pt_ID') was not necessary in this plot (at least for plotting the regression line) as the averaged values would still be the same. However, I soon realised that omitting Pt_ID changes both the line of the plot and confidence intervals (some as in this graph are even negative i.e., implausible):

```r
agg_forplot2 <- aggregate(Response ~ sumpdi+ Condition, df_forplot, 
                          FUN=mean)
    
Plot_C2 <- ggplot(agg_forplot2, aes(x=sumpdi, y=Response, 
                                    colour=Condition)) + 
         geom_smooth(method='lm', se=T, fill='light blue') + 
         geom_point() +
         ylab("Mean % 'Tone Present' Responses") +
         xlab('Summary PDI Score') + labs(color= 'Condition') +
         scale_color_manual(labels = c("No tone", "25%"), 
         values= c("#5CC0C0","#FF88FF"))
```

[image: Plot C2]

I realise this must have something to do with variation between participants. Can someone explain

1. the difference between the graphs and why Plot_C2 is more accurate?
2. I have read about the function SummarySEwithin (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Rmisc/versions/1.5.1/topics/summarySEwithin) and am not sure whether this should be used here?